# VS code with docker interpreter. Can't import module

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, module

I'm working in remote interpreter in VS code. Seems it works well but...
I created a folder (module) "utils" with some code. Then I created another module named data_load in there one file 'data_loader.py'. In this file I try to import module from utils. But VScode rise an error that such module is not found. I tried to run same structure in pycharm and it works. Please, help me to solve this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/workspace/docker-examples/pych/data_load/data_loader.py", line 16, in <module>
    from utils.util import XyzTuple, xyz2irc ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

[dirs in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2UFf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This means the parent folder of `utils` folder was not in the `PYTHONPATH` variable in the VSCode, while it was in it in the PyCharm. You can get the `PYTHONPATH` through this:

```
import sys
from pprint import  pprint
pprint(sys.path)
```

In the VSCode, you can do this to modify the `PYTHONPATH`:

1. Add these in the settings.json file to Modify the `PYTHONPATH` in the terminal:

   **"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "xxx/site-packages"
   }**
2. Create a `.env` file under your workspace, and add these settings in it to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for the extension and debugger:
   **PYTHONPATH=xxx/site-packages**

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) to understand the effects of these two configurations.

3. Modify it directly in the python file. Add these codes in the b.py file.

   **import sys; sys.path.append("xxx/Project/src")**